# Jasper Server: image absolute path to shared network drive

Tags: image, jasper-reports, jasperserver, absolute-path, shared-directory

I've been struggling with this issue for the last several days and can not figure out a workaround... Maybe somebody will be able to help me :)

I am trying to make a jasperserver report with dynamic images, stored on a network (shared network folder on different windows machine).

In iReport I define `Image Expression` as `\\SERVER_NAME\IMAGES\\CAMERA_NAME\\000-000.jpg` `Image Expression Class` as `java.lang.String` - everything works fine.

Even getting the image location and file name from the DB and forming `Image Expression` like so: `$F{ADRESSS}+"\\"+$F{CAMERA_NAME}+"."+$F{FILE_NAME}` is no problem at all. But when I upload my working report onto JasperServer, I get a lot of errors and nothing is being displayed.

I have tried defining static part of the image path like a string parameter and have tried changing `Image Expression Class` to every possible option with no result :(

I know that by default jasperserver wants all the images to be somewhere in `repo:` or be accessed via a web url, but in my case this is not an option: I can not copy all the images to a repo or store them locally, because I have to many of them (TB or so). Also I can not "publish" and make them accessible via web url due to security reasons.

Maybe someone has experienced the same problem and knows a solution? Or maybe I am trying to do the impossible thing here?

P.S.:
I am running JasperServer CE 5.5 on Win Server 2008 R2 machine.
Warehouse server holding several TB of images in its file-structure is also running on Win Server 2008 R2.
Both jasperserver and image warehouse machines see each other via the network (tested by running iReport report on jasperserver machine).

Comment: Post your jrxml file. where you are using image expression.

Comment: Hmm, I can't just past my code here, so this is my test report: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B65aCmneb3oxRkhYWFpNWTRBbjA/edit?usp=sharing Nothing fancy there, just trying to load one image from my server. This report actually works on iReport.

Comment: What error you are getting on server?

Comment: Basically, I get `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Byte data not found at : \\SURINKSRV1\SURINKDATA\Vaizdo kamera\Ramygala\2014\Liepos\02\11-00-00.jpg` Full error trace: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B65aCmneb3oxM01NTFI4V21mSGc/edit?usp=sharing